# Saving Video from Webcam with timestamps associated with each frame in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, video, encoding

EDIT:

What's the best way to record from a webcam and encode the timestamp for each frame down to millisecond resolution? What video format/codec should be used?
I have tried very hard at installing xuggler but could not do it. Using JCodec's SequenceEncoder in a Producer/Consumer paradigm but it's too slow.

```
      public class WebcamProducerConsumer {
        //
        private Producer p;
        private Consumer c;
        private BlockingQueue<BufferedImageAndTimeLong> sharedQueue;

        public WebcamProducerConsumer() throws IOException {
            sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<BufferedImageAndTimeLong>();
            p = new Producer(sharedQueue);
            c = new Consumer(sharedQueue);
        }
        public void start(Webcam cam){
            p.setUpCamera(cam);
            p.startCamera();
            System.out.println("Cam set up");
            Thread pThread = new Thread(p);
            Thread cThread = new Thread(c);
            pThread.start();
            cThread.start();
            System.out.println("P and C running");

        }
        public void startSaving(File f){
            try {
                c.startSaving(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void finishSaving() throws IOException{
            p.sendSentinel();
            System.out.println("Saving Done");
        }
        public void closeWebcamProducerConsumer() throws IOException{
            p.kill();
            c.kill();
        }

    }

    public class Producer implements Runnable {

        private BlockingQueue<BufferedImageAndTimeLong> sharedQueue;
        private Webcam webcam;
        private boolean capturing;


        public Producer(BlockingQueue<BufferedImageAndTimeLong> sharedQueue) {
            this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
            capturing = false;
        }

        public void setUpCamera(Webcam wb){
            webcam = wb;

        }
        public void startCamera(){
            webcam.open();
            capturing = true;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while(capturing){//eh?
                try{
            sharedQueue.add(new BufferedImageAndTimeLong(webcam.getImage(), System.nanoTime()));}
                catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Camera was not opened");
                }
                System.out.println(sharedQueue.size());
            }
            if (!capturing){
                sharedQueue.add(null);
            }
        }

        public synchronized void kill() {
            sharedQueue.add(null);
            capturing = false;

        }
        public void sendSentinel(){
            sharedQueue.add(new BufferedImageAndTimeLong(null, -1));
        }
    }

    public class Consumer{
        public synchronized void  run() {
            while(recording){
                BufferedImageAndTimeLong bitl;
                try {
                    bitl = sharedQueue.take();
                    if (bitl.getTimeLong()!= -1){

                        currentImage = bitl.getBufferedImage();
                    //  System.out.println(bitl.getTimeLong());
                        if (saving){
                            enc.encodeImage(currentImage);

                        //  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SequenceEncoder is null!");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        enc.finish();
                        saving = false;
                    }   
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void kill() throws IOException{
            recording = false;
        }

        public void startSaving(File f) throws IOException{
            enc = new SequenceEncoder(f);
            saving = true;
        }
        /*
        public void finishSaving() throws IOException{
            try{
                saving = false;
                savingStateChanging = true;
                System.out.println("Saving Complete");
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "SequenceEncoder is null!");
            }
        }
        */
        public BufferedImage getCurrentImage(){
            return currentImage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, please keep the questiosn short and to the point, post some code to   help people view your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried my best to shorten the question. Though I probably posted way more code than I should have.